# How to determine USB OTG mode on Linux

Tags: linux, usb, usb-2

I have got an i.MX6 device, which has a USB OTG port.

Is there a way in Linux to find out whether that USB OTG port is currently in host mode or in peripheral mode?

I tried `dmesg | grep -i otg` and `lsusb -v | grep -i otg` but nothing interesting turned up.

If the USB OTG port is in peripheral mode, then no other peripherals can be attached to the USB OTG port, so `lsusb` should be empty except for the host controller. But still, that might also be the result of some other problem, and doesn't necessarily indicate that the port is in peripheral mode.

So, how to reliably determine the USB OTG port OTG mode?

Comment: Do you mean you have Linux running on the device or you have the device connected to a computer with Linux running through its OTG port?

Comment: AFAIK, the mode of the port depends on the cable connected to it: http://tech.firstpost.com/wp-content/uploads/gallery/2012/jun/difference_circuit_271738111300_640x360.jpg (Regular: peripheral; OTG: host)

Comment: I have Linux running on the i.MX6 device, which has an OTG port.

Right, the mode depends on the cable, and it isn't (easily) possible to know which kind of cable I have by looking at it. Moreover, there also is a boot parameter that can force a specific mode (otg_mode=...). Given those combinations, I was wondering if there is a way to figure out the actual mode at runtime, with some command.

Comment: How did you know about this boot param `otg_mode`? To be honest I've never heard of it...and it's not on here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt

Comment: I think the ``otg_mode`` boot parameter is driver specific, it only exists for certain boards. For example the page http://xlon.de/wiki/index.php?title=USB_Mass_Storage_Gadget_%28or_MSG%29 talks about it.

Comment: Or actually some custom kernel...it isn't even belong to a certain module...(like, `$MODULE_NAME.otg_mode=device`)